# I need to convert apache rewrite to nginx

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

I need to convert apache mod_rewrite rules to nginx
please help !

Apache rewrite rules is :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?p=site&d=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^images/w-([0-9]+)-(.*).*$ img/rsc.php?w=$1&ph=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/h-([0-9]+)-(.*).*$ img/rsc.php?h=$1&ph=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html  This page explains how to use nginx rewrite.